# Debug address sanitizer double free

Tags: linux, address-sanitizer

Trying to debug an asan (address sanitizer) double free memory issue. I got this stack:

```
    ==4108==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting double-free on 0x603000012610 in thread T0:
    #0 0x7ffffe5212c0 in operator delete(void*) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4.0.0+0xe12c0)
    #1 0x7ffffc3806d4 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:125
    #2 0x7ffffc3806d4 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(std::allocator<char>&, char*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:462
    #3 0x7ffffc3806d4 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_destroy(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:226
    #4 0x7ffffc3806d4 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:221
    #5 0x7ffffc3806d4 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:647
    #6 0x7ffffc3806d4 in void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:140
    #7 0x7ffffc3806d4 in void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_List_node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::allocator<std::_List_node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:487
    #8 0x7ffffc3806d4 in std::__cxx11::_List_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_clear() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/list.tcc:76
    #9 0x7ffffc381327 in std::__cxx11::_List_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::~_List_base() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:442
    #10 0x7ffffc381327 in std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::~list() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:733
    #11 0x7ffffc381327 in std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::~pair() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:208
    #12 0x7ffffc381327 in void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >::destroy<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >*) /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:140
    #13 0x7ffffc381327 in void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > > >::destroy<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >(std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >&, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >*) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:487
    #14 0x7ffffc381327 in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >::_M_destroy_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >*) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:650
    #15 0x7ffffc381327 in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >::_M_drop_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >*) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:658
    #16 0x7ffffc381327 in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >*) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:1858
    #17 0x7ffffc38131a in std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >*) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_tree.h:1856
    #18 0x7ffffd173614 in __cxa_finalize (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x43614)
    #19 0x7ffffc325ef2  (/home/ghita/wk/ah-sdk/ah/build/ah-linux-ubuntu-1804/debug/ah-sdk-dialog/ah.so+0x82ef2)

0x603000012610 is located 0 bytes inside of 24-byte region [0x603000012610,0x603000012628)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7ffffe5212c0 in operator delete(void*) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4.0.0+0xe12c0)
    #1 0x7ffffe145ba4 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:125
    #2 0x7ffffe145ba4 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(std::allocator<char>&, char*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:462
    #3 0x7ffffe145ba4 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_destroy(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:226
    #4 0x7ffffe145ba4 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:221
    #5 0x7ffffe145ba4 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:647
    #6 0x7ffffe145ba4 in void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:140
    #7 0x7ffffe145ba4 in void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_List_node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::allocator<std::_List_node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:487
    #8 0x7ffffe145ba4 in std::__cxx11::_List_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_clear() /usr/include/c++/7/bits/list.tcc:76

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7ffffe520448 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4.0.0+0xe0448)
    #1 0x7ffffe14175c in void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.tcc:219

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: double-free (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4.0.0+0xe12c0) in operator delete(void*)
==4108==ABORTING

Thread 1 "app" hit Breakpoint 2, __sanitizer::Die () at ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_termination.cc:49
49      ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_termination.cc: No such file or directory.
```

Might be some global object or something, cannot figure out a way under debugger to detect the instance. Setting a breakpoint on __asan::ReportGenericError does not help.

Comment: Seeing somebody tring to close this. Very prolific person, without any clues if this is a valid question to ask or not ?

Comment: Found out that is indeed caused by some global object destruction, only see STL types in the stack, which is hard to link to something specific from code though.

Comment: you are deleting some wrong memory that you are not allowed to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the stack it can be seen that the type involved (in destruction) is std::pair<std::string, std::list<>>. Looking over the code where this is used solved the issue. If there are multiple type instances used in many different places it will be hard identifying though.

Comment: "Looking over the code where this is used solve dthe issue." is a very low quality answer (IMO). It is certainly unlikely to help anyone else (which is the purpose of SO). Consider deleting both the question, and the answer.

Comment: Ok, agreeto disagree. I mentioned the type involved, can be seen in the initial callstack. That is the finding  and is valuable (no other hints that solved this). Keep downvoting this won't make yours better.